# Configuring Mail.app "From" drop-down menu?

Tags: mail.app, email, accounts, macos

When I write a mail in Mail.app (using MacOS X Mavericks 10.9.2 here), I have this "From" Drop down menu which allows me to select from which of my accounts I want to send that mail.

In my case, this drop-down menu has 33 items.

How is this menu configured?

I ask because it is tied to the account list, but not quite the same. My account list has only 17 items for example.

I have a few forward email addresses that show up there, but not all.

At this moment, I would like to have one of my email sent with a "From" header that is a forward email address that doesn't show up in that menu.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to do this.

The From field could be preselected in the mail preferences, using the dropdown and select From that would be ALWAYS used from now on.

I still have it as choice since i use multiple emails and want to choose the From.

[image: From]

Next is the multitude of From's, way more then actual email accounts.

Called the smtp servers list

That can be resolved by DELETING all duplicates and others, and leaving only the one you actually have and use.

[image: smtp]

In drop down Click on edit smtp list and delete the one you do not want.